# JavaFX : How to control input in a TextField ?

Tags: javafx, textfield

I try to do an application with JavaFX. 
I have a little question :

- I have a TextField and i would like it will be a TextField for "phone number" (0477/40.00.09 for example).

Unfortunatly, i can't do this. 
I would like that '/' and '.' are always write in the TextField.
I also would like when the user has wrote the fourth first numbers, the TextField set the cursor behind the '/'. So the user don't take care for '/' and '.'. He has just to type the number of the phone number.

How can i do this ?

Thanks for your help,

Mikis

(Sorry for my English ....)

Comment: Does the `/` always comes after 4 digits?

Comment: Yes a phone number is format (in belgium) like this 

- 4 digits
- / 
-2 digits
- .
2 digits
- . 
- 2 digits

Comment: Does the `/ `editable ,i mean the user can not delete symbole ?

Comment: This is exact, the user cannot delete the symbol '/' and '.'

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to control the text inside a TextField.

PhoneNumber TextField described in the question should do the following:

- Add `/` after 4 characters
- Add `.` after 7 and 10 characters
- Doesn't allow more than 13 characters

Here is a sample which does all of the above:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldFormatter extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(change -> {

            final int oldLength = change.getControlText().length();
            int newLength = change.getControlNewText().length();

            // Handle backspace
            if (newLength < oldLength) return change;

            // Add / after 4 characters
            // Add . after 7 and 10 characters
            // Do not accept more than 13 characters
            switch (newLength) {
                case 4 :
                    change.setText(change.getText() + "/"); 
                    newLength++;
                    break;
                case 7: case 10:
                    change.setText(change.getText() + "."); 
                    newLength++;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    return null;
            }
            // Set caret position
            change.setCaretPosition(newLength);
            change.setAnchor(newLength);
            return change;
        }));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(textField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("TextField Example");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok for the TextFormatter, it does a part of what i want :)

But the user didn't see the '/' and the '.' before enter the digits ? I want that user can see "    /  .  .  " in the TextField (always, not a prompt text).

Comment: I do not recommend implementing the formatter like this. A user could "input" multiple chars at once by copy&paste. This means you may never match the exact lengths used in the switch statement or the modifications may be triggered at the wrong time.

Comment: What do you recommend ?

Comment: @fabian There are ways to get through that. This is a simple implementations and of course has it flaws :)

Comment: @MikisMillemaci Do you want the initial state of TextField as 4 spaces followed by `/` and so on?

Comment: No, i didn't use it because i don't use a fxml sheet in my project. Is there a way to use it without fxml ?

Comment: It is just a custom control. You can use it with or without FXML.

Comment: Why i get this warning warning : `Redundant type arguments in new expression (use diamond operator instead)` ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine It's because the Java compiler is getting smarter with each release. You can replace `new TextFormatter<String>` with `new TextFormatter<>`.

Comment: Yeah of course i did what your mentionned .Thank you @ItachiUchiha .

Answer (score 0):

You can `addListener()` to TextField `propertyText` and control the inputs.In your question you did not put any condition so just you need a useful implementation for that you can use this simple code :

```
 TextField field = new TextField();

    field.setPromptText("xxxx/xx.xx.xx");
        int maxDigits = 13;
        field.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.length() == 4 && oldValue.length() != 5) {
                field.setText(newValue + "/");
            } else if (newValue.length() == 7 && oldValue.length() != 8 || newValue.length() == 10 && oldValue.length() != 13) {
                field.setText(newValue + ".");
            }
            if (newValue.length() > maxDigits) {
                field.setText(oldValue);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Ok, this is a good way to do what i want. Thank you. 
Is there a way to always have the "    /  .  .  "  ? This can be usefull for the user, si he always has to put the digits. And the '/' and '.' cannot be deleted.

Comment: Of course ,If you need change the formatter of your textfield in the future just  change `4` to other variable and your symbols `.` `/`  .

Comment: For example if you need  `x `digits before `/` ,just change `4` to `x` and fallow this rule : `newValue.length() == x && oldValue.length() != x+1`.

Comment: When you click on the TextField, the prompt text disappear. I want that text always remainds. So the user enter '0477' and after that the TextField automaticaly set the cursor behind the '/' and the user continue with '00' and then automaticaly '.' ....

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, i found what i was searching in this project :

https://github.com/jidesoft/jidefx-oss

But i adapted it to my needs. Do I put the code for the new object "MyMaskTextField" ?